# Fast switching between two lines in file in vim

Tags: vim

sometimes I have to switch between 2 lines. To do this, I have to pass line number. Are there shortcuts to moving between 2 last 'visited' list. Something similar to `'.` (it moves to last edited line)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use bookmarks, something like <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to mark a bookmark named `a`, and then <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to go to it. Naming boomarks `a` and `b` for example, you can switch between them with <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to have global bookmarks to swiching between files?

Comment: Use capital letters A-Z for global bookmarks across files.  Look at `:help :marks` or `:help '` for more info - after the command reference there are descriptions of marks a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

Answer (score 16):

#### Double-backtick or double single-quote will do exactly that

There is a command that will bounce to the last location you jumped away from. If repeated, it will then return to the jump destination you were just on. If repeated further it will bounce you back and forth between the two locations.

The command has two forms:

```
``
```

or

```
''
```

Answer (score 8):

`ctrl-o` and `ctrl-i` will move backwards and forwards through your history of jump points.  A jump point is pretty much any command that moves the cursor more than one line.  It will also go back to previous files that were loaded into the current buffer.

See `:h jump-motions` for more information.